# How can i supply value to Textbox generate from @Html.EditorFor in MVC razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am just new to MVC.

when we use "@Html.EditorFor" in razor view, it generates textbox.

My requirement is that  I need to supply some value from viewbag or session to user's in that textbox?

Is it possible and if yes how can i do?

OR

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action method in the controller, pre-load a model with some data:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.FirstName = "Bob";
    model.LastName = "Hoskins";

    return View(model);
}
```

Then make your View strongly typed.  These pre-set values should now appear on your view.  You probably want to populate them from a service layer or resource file, rather than have them as hardcoded strings like my example.